# What is the best method to set image sources?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a website that has expand-collapse icons. In my localhost, it works fine. however, once online, the images are not displayed in mozilla (displayed in IE). in my image sources, I have used absolute links `src="http://example/icons/expand.png"` instead of relative `src="/icons/expand.png`. I do not understand why images are not displayed in mozilla.
I do not know if using absolute links for images sources is a good practice, so I need your help.

Comment: are you getting some error in browser like `image not found` or anything else?

Comment: I do not get `not found` error. the image area contains nothing. in IE i see the image but in mozilla the image is not displayed. the images is a little png icon.

Comment: it is possible to share a **plnkr** link or any other URL to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I found the problem. the images where blocked by Mozilla for security. Thank you very much for your help. However i want to know the good practice between `src="/icons/expand.png` and `src="http://example/icons/png`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, is best practice to use relative links, because you can resize and minimize the images to let users load the page faster. You can use softwares like Gimp or Photoshop to minimize them and then upload to your online space.
Hope to help you :)